Three.js Elements render Issue
I have a three.js website hosted on prathamu.com. However On some devices some elements dont render in properly.[enter image description here](enter image description herehttps://i.sstatic.net/oJcLcqJA.jpg)
I tried compressing all the 3d elements and reducend the number of components too

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
